# Will Redux inside a React component from npm conflict with the container's Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux

I want to encapsulate a npm React component, and I want to use Redux to manage state inside this React component.
When another React project imports my component, will this React project's redux instance have conflict with my React component?

Here is the example:
The component will look like:

```
// File Explorer Component, will be build into a npm package
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";
function FileExplorer({source}) {
  <Provider store={store}>
     {/* there will be complicated business logic inside */}
  </Provider>;
}
```

Then, I create another React project, and import the `FileExplorer` component from npm

index.jsx

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store"; // this store is a different one
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.jsx

```
import FileExplorer from 'file-explorer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <FileExplorer source={'https://example.com/data/v1/files'} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you considered React Context? Is there a specific reason to use Redux?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "use Redux to manage state _inside_ the React component"?  This seems very unusual and I'd like to hear more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @freakomonk There will be complicated data structure. It easier to manage these data with Redux rather than React Context.

Comment: @markerikson I just edited the description and added a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple thoughts here.

The first is yes, this would absolutely cause a clash if the components nested inside of `<FileExplorer>` also need to access the app-wide Redux store, because by default all Redux-connected React components access the same store instance via React context.

It *is* technically possible to pass an alternate context to `<Provider>` and create customized versions of `useSelector/useDispatch` that read the store from that context:

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#providing-custom-context

although it looks like we don't actually document the API for creating the context-customized versions of the selector hooks atm.

React-Redux should be exporting `createSelectorHook` and `createDispatchHooks` functions, which you can see in use here:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v7.2.6/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L166

Should be used as:

`const useCustomContextSelector = createSelectorHook(MyCustomContext);`

All that said: I'd still lean towards tracking the state in a `useReducer` hook as the default rather than an actual separate Redux store.

Note that you can use RTK's `createSlice` to create a reducer specifically for use in a `useReducer` hook - reducer functions are just functions and work fine in either place.

Comment: `useReducer` + `createSlice` is such a powerful method! This is exactly what I want. However, when the state is getting complicated, is there a way to combine the reducers created by `createSlice` for `useReducer`, just like `combineReducers` in `redux`?

Comment: Everything that I just said about `createSlice` and reducers also applies to `combineReducers`! It's _just_ a function that creates another reducer. So, if you've already added RTK, you can `import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'` and combine them just like you would with a Redux store.